# ASP.Net - FileUpload HasFile is always false and FileName is always empty

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I have the following inside an .ascx file.

```
 <asp:Panel runat="server" Height="200">
       <div class="col50">
        <div class="col100" style="padding-bottom: 4px; float: left">
            <div class="col50">
                <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text="Fee Split">
                 </asp:Label>                  
            </div>
            <div class="col50">
                <asp:CheckBox ID="IsFeeSplitCheck" Enabled="false" 
                     runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col100" style="padding-bottom: 4px; float: left">
            <div class="col50">
                <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text="R"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col50">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col100" style="padding-bottom: 4px; float: left">

            <div class="col50" style="text-align: left;">
                <asp:Label ID="lblLogo" runat="server" Text="Practice Logo">
                </asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="col50">                   
                          <asp:FileUpload ID="fuCompanyLogo" 
                  ViewStateMode="Enabled" Enabled="true" runat="server"  />                                                                                         
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col100" style="padding-bottom: 4px; float: left">
    <div class="col25">
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text="  "></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div class="col75">
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAssetAllocation" Font-Bold="true" 
            AutoPostBack="false" runat="server" Text="D"/>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Panel>
```

"HasFile" of FileUpload always returns always no matter how many times I upload. And, at the same time file name is always an empty string.

Can someone give a solution to this ?

Comment: Try putting this line in `Page_Load` event: `this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data"`. If you have `UpdatePanel` to wrap `FileUpload` it requires postback trigger: `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="fuCompanyLogo" ... />`.

Comment: This postback trigger does not work. It says postbacktrigger cannot be applied to file upload panel

Comment: this.Page.Form.Enctype = "multipart/form-data" does not work :(

Comment: The postback trigger usually placed on `asp:Button` (I missed the fact that you haven't tell what button to submit the form yet). Perhaps an `asp:UpdatePanel` is required to wrap your `FileUpload`.

Comment: Any chance the file you're trying to upload is empty? `HasFile` returns false if the file is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I had a similar problem. Adding a PostBackTrigger tag at the end of the UpdatePanel fixed it for me.

```html
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>     
        <asp:Panel id="popup" visible="false" runat="server" BackColor="#9AD6E4" BorderColor="#2F99BA" style="border-radius: 0.30em;" 
                 Width="580px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
            <br />
            <div style="text-align: center; font-style:italic; font-size: small; font-weight:bold;" ><asp:Label ID="TitleLabel" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <asp:Label ID="LabMSG" runat="server" Text="" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
      <table style="background-color: #9AD6E4; padding: 5px">
       <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="LabelA1" runat="server" Text="To:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextTO" runat="server" MaxLength="50" width="20em"></asp:TextBox></td>
       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFCN00" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="*" 
            Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="Add" ControlToValidate="TextTO">To: Required
       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

      <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valEmailTo"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid To: email. "
           ControlToValidate="TextTO" ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="LabelA2" runat="server" Text="CC:"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextCC" runat="server" MaxLength="50" width="20em"></asp:TextBox></td>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="valEmailCC"  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid CC: email."
           ControlToValidate="TextCC" ValidationExpression="^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$" />
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" Text="Subject:"></asp:Label></td>
     <td><asp:Label ID="wSubjct" runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
       <asp:Label ID="LabelAttachFile" runat="server" Text="Attach File:"></asp:Label></td>
      <td>
        <asp:FileUpload  ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" Width="25em" />
      </td>                                   
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
     <tr>
       <td class="auto-style2">
         <asp:Button  CssClass="button" ID="btSend" runat="server" Text="Send eMail" OnClick="Send_Click" />
         
      </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table>
     <tr><td>
     <asp:TextBox ID="TextToEdit" runat="server" MaxLength="180" width="48em" TextMode="Multiline" rows="3" Visible="false" ></asp:TextBox>
      </td></tr>
   </table>              
  </asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate>
 <Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btSend" /> 
  </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```